# Is it ok to attempt to reply to a question - not having scriptural evidence?

Tags: discussion, answers

There is a question that is currently marked to be closed. I would like to attempt to reply to that question - [Would Karna have become the heir to the throne if he survived the war?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24544/3294)
but I cannot find scriptural evidence to what I want to say.

is it something that would be good for our forum or not? I don't want to start a discussion as this is not the purpose of this forum.

I don't want to upset any Mahatmas here in the forum by breaking any rules.

I don't have personal evidence either for this question.

Comment: In that case, A comment reply should be fine IMO.